# woocommerce paypal advanced authentication error

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I have bought woocommerce paypal advanced plugin.

I have enabled sandbox account.

I am using my seller id in admin and try to test product buying using buyer account..

but when I try to do it it shows me error every time

is that some thing wrong or misconfiguration

here is the error message, should I try with my actual paypal advance account as its not working with sandbox id?

**Error:**

> "There was an error processing your order - User authentication failed"

Answer (score 4):

You receive this error message if the Payflow servers are unable to authenticate your request due to one of the following reasons:

- The account information (USER, VENDOR, PARTNER and PASSWORD) that is being passed does not match the login information at PayPal, which causes your request to be rejected.
- Missing the PARTNER field.
- There are invalid or special characters used in password.
- Transactions are being sent to the live servers on a test account.
- The processor information or the status of your processor on your account is incorrect or invalid.
- The IP address or range of addresses that the transactions are sent from do not match the IP address(es) listed in PayPal Manager.
- You are sending recurring billing transactions to a LIVE account without the recurring billing service activated.
- The transaction in question (delayed capture or credit) is sent to a different Payflow account, which is associated with a different processor (Paymentech, Nova (Elavon), and so forth) than the original transaction.

Please verify you are using the appropriate PARTNER/VENDOR/USER/PASSWORD combination for your API credentials and the API request is being sent to the appropriate live or test endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Acutually i was using wrong password for that.Anyone who has paypal advanced plugin need to Login to paypal manager first.And use the login id and password of paypal manager

here is the link for that

https://manager.paypal.com/

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you change a password at the PayPal Manager Account (PMA). Once you change a password at PMA, you need to change in in the Wordpress/WooCommerce/Settings/Payment Gateways/Paypal Advanced